# What does an asterisk in front of a constant mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I see this `*MyModel::MY_CONSTANT`

and it references this in MyModel:

```
  MY_CONSTANT = [
    :a_field,
    :another_field,
  [
```

When called as

```
permit(:name, *MyModel::MY_CONSTANT)
```

it expands to

```
permit(:name, :a_field, :b_field)
```

but what just happened?

Comment: Probably more than you ever wanted to know about it here: https://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope that it actually expanded to `permit(:name, :a_field, :another_field)` :)  But yeah, basically that's what it does when used on an array, it takes the values of the array and expands them out as if they were provided as individual arguments.  So then you can take those array elements and send them into a method that's expecting individual arguments.

You can also use it in the inverse, you can define a method like:

```
def foo *args
end
```

...and when it's called with individual arguments:

```
foo 'a', 'b', 'c'
```

...those end up inside the `foo` method in the array `args` - this is very handy for wrapping another method, eg.

```
def some_method *args
  do_something args.first
  super *args   # call the superclass's `some_method` with whatever args it would have received
end
```

#### Update

Btw, [here's the official docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion) about this operator.